# Getter and Setter of Model object in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I make getter and setter work in my model class?

My goal is to calculate integer value of the selected day when input, containing the date, updated. I was going to do it in setter, but Angular 4 ignores setter and getter of my model.

My model class:

```
export class MyModel {
    @Input('date')
    get date(): String {
        console.log('Getting date');
        ...
    }

    set date(val) {
        console.log('Setting date: ' + val);
        ...
    }
}
```

My template:

```
...
<input class="form-control" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model.date">
...
```

But getter and setter don't work. What am I missing?

Comment: This syntax `@Input('date')` is only for properties of nested components. The decorator doesn't belong on a model class property.

Comment: Could you also show your code for your component class and how it is using this model class?

Comment: @DeborahK  if we are passing data to a nested component from a service.  are Inputs the only way with getters?

Comment: No. The purpose of Input property (`@Input`) is to allow a parent component to pass data to a child component as part of the Html element binding: `<app-mychild [startDate]='somedate'></app-mychild>` It is not needed when using properties from a service.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The way you declare the date property as an input looks incorrect but its hard to say if it's the only problem without seeing all your code. Rather than using `@Input('date')` declare the date property like so: `private _date: string;`. Also, make sure you are instantiating the model with the `new` keyword. Lastly, access the property using regular dot notation.

Check your work against this example from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html :

```
let passcode = "secret passcode";

class Employee {
    private _fullName: string;

    get fullName(): string {
        return this._fullName;
    }

    set fullName(newName: string) {
        if (passcode && passcode == "secret passcode") {
            this._fullName = newName;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error: Unauthorized update of employee!");
        }
    }
}

let employee = new Employee();
employee.fullName = "Bob Smith";
if (employee.fullName) {
    console.log(employee.fullName);
}
```

And here is a plunker demonstrating what it sounds like you're trying to do:
https://plnkr.co/edit/OUoD5J1lfO6bIeME9N0F?p=preview