# Input text box binding failing to set but working on get of an Angular property

Tags: angular, data-binding

I noticed that the following binding seems to produce the correct behavior in regard to *set* property but isn't invoked when setting the value.

```html
<input (keyup)="onKeyUp()" value={{config.rendition}}>
```

```ts
export class RowConfig {
  constructor(public amount = 0, ... ) { }

  get rendition() { return this.amount + "$"; }
  set rendition(input: string) {
    console.log("setter with '" + input + "' invoked");
    const numeric = input.replace("$", "");
    this.amount = +numeric;
  }
}
```

The `keyup` is performed as supposed to but the setter of `rendition` doesn't print anything to the console so I'm assuming it's not bound properly and/or isn't bindable at all.

I'm loosely following [stuff like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44511577/1525840) and I have a [Blitzy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urryal) of the behavior to play with.

Googling was a bit difficult because of the collision between `input` as a tag and `@Input` as a decorator. The latter won by far... What I gathered, though, was to either bind using `[(ngModel)]` or to use directives or pipes. All of the trails seemed a bit uncertain in relevance and/or reliability. Hence the demo on StackBlitz.

Comment: Where is the method for `onKeyUp`?

Comment: @wentjun In the component using the config class as *@Input*. Class *EditableRowComponent* at line 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div *ngIf="config.editing">
  <input #first type="text" placeholder="xxx xx aaaa..." [(ngModel)]="config.first">
  <input #second type="text" placeholder="xxx aaaa..." [(ngModel)]="config.second">
  <input #amount type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp()" placeholder="xxx" [(ngModel)]="config.rendition">
  <input (click)="onSave()" type="button" value="save">
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give it a try (it's one of the suggestions I've found goolging). However, I'd feel much more at ease if I could understand **why** I have to use it. It feels to me like if I'm approaching it the wrong way. How come it's required with *ngModel* for setter but not getter (nor setting/getting the other properties at all)? It's seems like only the explicit getter is an issue and I haven't found any references in docs that mention that.

Comment: It definitely seems to work (answer accepted). However, I'm now under the impression of black magic. Where do we say that it's **value** of the input that we bind? Why don't we have to do that for getter of *rendition* and not for getting or setting the other properties? I'm rather confused on the nuts and bolts of this behavior. Would using a pipe and/or directive be a smarter approach?

Comment: value={{config.rendition}} - couldn't work. This transforms to: value=propertyValue; Two way binding normaly works with [(...)] Syntax. Unfortunately I don't know why [(value)]="config.rendition" doesn't work here.. :/

Comment: Oh, that might be something that **I might be** helpful with. I've been told that the two-way binding on properties of fields (i.e. not *{{blah}}* but *{{config.blah}}* are actually not boundable as such (since it relies on *SimpleChanges*). So the trick is to rely on a series of one-way bindings that are for our sanity and convenience packed up into *ngModel* thingy that does al the sweating. NB. I'm taking no responsibility for the above claim. It's strictly *a dude told me once...* based. Now, it's +1 for the extra effort, of course. Do you have any thought on pipe/directive here?

Comment: Thanks for the +1 :).
Pipe/Directive instead of your get/set? If I understand it right your just adding the '$' character or? That's a common problem for a currency mask - I had that problem too and found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask
If it doesn't fit for your needs it's a good code base. I copied and edited it for my needs..

Comment: Naa, it's a bit more complex than so. I'm just trying to digest down the issue so SO won't have to do the work for me. The actual requirement is to put in spaces between groups of three digits and not allowing non-digits. Also, each key press needs to be sent to the parent for other recalculations (while editing, yes). I have almost got it working, thanks to you. Only a single issue remains now. Feel free to take a peek, if you have time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994358/control-bound-to-a-model-shows-old-value-on-certain-keys-despite-get-property