# Control bound to a model shows old value on certain keys despite get property() working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

First of all, sorry for the cryptic question. I'll update gladly if someone suggests something better. Perhaps it's my diagnostics that aren't well directed.

I have a config class that has a field. There's a input box bound to that field and, since the requirment is a bit complex, I implemented `get` and `set` methods for it. The design looks like this.

```
export class RowConfig {
  constructor(public amount = 0, ...) { }

  get rendition() {
    let output = "";
    if (this.amount !== null && this.amount !== undefined)
      output = ("" + this.amount)
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ");

    console.log("rendition GET: " + this.amount + " -> " + output);
    return output;
  }
  set rendition(input: string) {
    console.log("rendition SET: " + input);
    const negative = input.match(/^[-]/);
    const digits = input.replace(/\D/g, "");
    let output = null;
    if (digits)
      output = +digits * (negative ? -1 : 1);
    this.amount = output;

    console.log("rendition ACT: " + output);
  }
}
```

At first, I assumed it was something with the regex (which it isn't). Then I though my model is bound in a way that `get rendition()` serves wrong value (which is doesn't). Clearly, the logic in the class performs as supposed to. However, when I enter *12345W*, the non-digit character stays in the input box! I can see in the console that the received string *12345W* is converted to and stored as the number *12345*. I can also see in the console that the rendered value returned is *12 345*, including the space, as supposed to.

Still, the value in the box shows *W* and I can't see why. When I eventually press a digit key, the control updates as expected and the non-digit is removed. So confused here...

```
<input #amount 
       type="text" 
       (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
       placeholder="xxx" [(ngModel)]="config.rendition">
```

I've tried acting on `keyup`, preventing defaults and stopping propagation. I've tried simplyfying the logic for when to alter the values. I can't see where I go wrong. The only suspicious thing I noticed is that `get rendition()` is called twice before and twice after the `set rendition()` is invoked (no that it tells me much and I can imagine it has to do with the Angular bubbling of events, somehow).

So at this point, I claim it's magic, the black kind. And I'll be greatly satisified if someone proves me wrong in [this nice Blitzy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rendered-value-shows-only-for-numbers).

Comment: yeah.. I think thats because the value doesn't change if you type in a non digit => no refresh. Just for testing => replace in setter "this.amount = output;" with "this.amount = 1;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.amount = output;
    }, 1);"

Comment: Correct. That's it. So the question now is - how do I **force** the bound value to tell the Angular engine that *never you mind, little buddy, what's been - put this on display*, right? Suggestions on how?

Comment: I had to ask a new question, now that the diagnostics are more accurate. Pitch in if you can [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995169/forcing-change-detection-when-value-bound-to-doesnt-change).