# Forcing change detection when value bound to doesn't change

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I have a component that reacts to a change in input control and reformats it by removing certain characters. When setting is done, the value stored in the backing field may change or not. In the first case, everything works but if the removed character maps to the previous value, there's no change detected and the component doesn't update. That leads to the value including the removable character stays in the input box.

How can I force an input box bound via *[(ngModel)]* to a backing field to actually update changing it's entered value to the one served by *get prop()* facility?

```
export class RowConfig {
  constructor(public amount = 0, ...) { }

  get rendition() {
    let output = "";
    if (this.amount !== null && this.amount !== undefined)
      output = ("" + this.amount)
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ");
    return output;
  }
  set rendition(input: string) {
    const negative = input.match(/^[-]/);
    const digits = input.replace(/\D/g, "");
    let output = null;
    if (digits)
      output = +digits * (negative ? -1 : 1);
    this.amount = output;
  }
}
```

The binding is done like this.

```
<input #amount type="text"
       (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
       [(ngModel)]="config.rendition">
```

I've tried to execute detection change in *onKeyUp* using *markForCheck()* and *detectChanges()* as declared [in docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#!#markForCheck-anchor). No difference there.

How can I force the input box to actual clear up the current content and replace it with the actual value from the bound property?

(Playable demo on [Blitzy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rendered-value-shows-only-for-numbers).)

Comment: Can you tell us what to do in the stackblitz to see the problem?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Sorry. If you click the recrangle, the third box (with *xxx*) receives an input. Try to punch in *12345* and you'll see the formatting to *12 345*. If you enter *12345m* and nothing happens but if you enter *12345m6*, the clensing kicks in. In the console, I print out the state of the backing field and *get rendition()* and those are correct. It's just that the input sees that the value bound to is still the same as it was before (although different from the box's contents). And then, the control doesn't update away the non-digit.

Comment: When I type `12345m`, I see `12 345` in the field (after seeing the `m` briefly). Isn't that correct?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I sweat to God it didn't before! Obviously, it's sorcery of some kind... That, or I confused two forks and incidentally fixed the other (I'm trying stuff myself so I don't rely on SO too much). My vote is 80-20 for sorcery... Thanks mate and terribly sorry to waste your time while you try to help. My bad, I guess.

Comment: @ConnorsFan As we're on the subject, I might as well ask about the briefly visible character there. Can you think of something to get rid of it? Or make it so brief that the eye doesn't catch it? I tried *onKeyDown* and played with directives but it didn't work the way one would like.

Comment: There is a way to avoid the visible invalid character but your setup makes it somewhat difficult to implement. I will try to find a workaround.

Comment: @ConnorsFan For pure academic reasons, I'd like to know how one might go about to get rid of the character - regardless of whether we can push it into our solution or not. (Regrettably, there are certain requirements that I have to obey, even if I disagee.) And should you have time to find something specifically targeting the current solution straight off, that's even better.

Comment: I added another example to the answer, to show how it can be implemented in simple cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to force the view to update even when the final value is the same as the existing one, is to first call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after setting the raw (and possibly invalid) value, and then to set the correct value.

For example, if you had a text field that accepts only digits, and if the processing was done in the component code, you could implement the setter as follows:

```
private _numericString: string;

get numericString() {
  return this._numericString;
}
set numericString(value) {
  this._numericString = value;     // <------------------------ Set the raw value
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();   // <--------------- Trigger change detection
  this._numericString = value.replace(/[^\d]/gi, ""); // <----- Set the corrected value
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rendered-value-shows-only-for-numbers-jezwzc?file=src/app/editable-row/editable-row.component.ts) for a demo.

---

In your actual code, `config.Rendition` is defined as a getter/setter property in a separate class, and the formatting is done in both `get` and `set`, making it more difficult to force change detection with the raw value. One way to circumvent that difficulty is to define a `configRendition` getter/setter property in the component and to assign that property to `ngModel`:

```
<input #amount type="text" placeholder="xxx" [(ngModel)]="configRendition">
```

We can then implement `configRendition` in such a way that `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` is called first with the raw value, before actually setting `config.Rendition`:

```
private rawRendition: string;

get configRendition() {
  if (this.rawRendition) {
    return this.rawRendition;
  } else {
    return this.config ? this.config.rendition : null;
  }
}
set configRendition(value) {
  this.rawRendition = value;
  this.detector.detectChanges();
  if (this.config) {
    this.config.rendition = value;
  }
  this.rawRendition = null;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rendered-value-shows-only-for-numbers-vytufh?file=src%2Fapp%2Feditable-row%2Feditable-row.component.ts) for a demo.