# How to create an Observable from a field

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, observer-pattern

I have a class called EditEmployee where I declare a field:

```js
export class EditEmployee implements OnInit {
  spaceRequirement = 0;
  ...
}
```

I want to make the `spaceRequirement` field an Observable so that in my `ngOnInit()` function, I can do this:

```js
export class EditEmployee implements OnInit {
  spaceRequirement = 0;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.spaceRequirement.subscribe(spaceReq => {
    //Call some function when spaceRequirement changes
  }
}
```

How can I make the `spaceRequirement` field an Observable so that I can call a function whenever that value changes?

Comment: add setter to your prop. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44511577/3933927)

Answer (score 3):

You can make it as `BehaviorSubject`

```
spaceRequirement = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

Then you can subscribe to it.
If you need to change its value you call:
`this.spaceRequirement.next(NEW_VALUE_HERE);`

Comment: Is there any other way I can make spaceRequirements an observable without instantiating it as a BehaviorSubject? Doing something like `spaceRequirement.makeObservable()` and then subscribing to it ?

Comment: I don't think so, this way you just create a `BehaviorSubject` which is an `Observable` at the same time and you can pass data to it. What's the issues with that solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a getter and a setter to access a behaviour subject and subscribe to the behavior subject to watch for changes.

```
spaceRequirement$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

get spaceRequirement(): number {
  return this.spaceRequirement$.value;
}

set spaceRequirement(val: number) {
  this.spaceRequirement$.next(val);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.spaceRequirement$.subscribe(spaceReq => {
  //Call some function when spaceRequirement changes
  }
}
```