# get as a separate word in an Angular method

Tags: angular, methods, get

I have come across the following Angular code at work (contained in a component):

```
getPerPage(): any {
    return (this.perPage === 'All' ? this.total : this.perPage);
}
get start(): number {
    return Math.min(Math.max(1 + (+this.current - 1)*+this.getPerPage(), 0), +this.total);
}
get end(): number {
    return Math.min(this.start + (this.getPerPage() - 1), +this.total);
}
private getPage(number: string | number, disabled = false): NglPage {
    return { number, disabled };
}
```

So there are two methods with a name that has get as part of the name, and two methods that have get as a separate word from the name. I took an Angular course in college, but we never discussed situations where get and set (I found that too) would be stand alone words in the declaration of a method. I'm having trouble getting information about this when I do searches on the Internet. Can anyone tell me why you would have get as a separate word when declaring a method as opposed to having get in the title of the method? And can anyone point me to a resource with more info about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getter and Setter of Model object in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508886/getter-and-setter-of-model-object-in-angular-4)

Comment: getter and setter. https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-getters-setters/